# Dynamic wrap grid

Tags: .net, wpf

Those check boxes are in a wrap panel. 
Is there a way to get dynamically aligned columns. 
And I mean each column is only as wide as it has to be. 
Not all columns the same width

This a sizeable Window.  The check boxes wrap as required. 
That is what a [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel(v=vs.110).aspx) does.  What I would like is for the check boxes to dynamically line up.  But I don't want to just up space of the widest to get that.

Sorry I was not clear. I do not want a fixed number of columns. I want to wrap dynamically and line up in columns.

UniformGrid does not do what I want on two counts. 
All columns are the same width and a fixed number of columns. 
If you leave Columns = out then it defaulted to 3 for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx) control. Here is an example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel Margin="10">
        <CheckBox Margin="5">All</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">Child</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">Parent</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">ParNoChild</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">ParHasChild</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">FamGT1</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">NoLock</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">AnyLock</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">CodeOnce</CheckBox>
    </WrapPanel>
    <UniformGrid Margin="10" Columns="4">
        <CheckBox Margin="5">All</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">Child</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">Parent</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">ParNoChild</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">ParHasChild</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">FamGT1</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">NoLock</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">AnyLock</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Margin="5">CodeOnce</CheckBox>
    </UniformGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

It will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Let me check this out but a I don't want a fixed number of columns. I realize my question was not clear.  Sorry.

Comment: +1 as it is not your fault the question was not clear.  I don't want a fixed number of columns.  If I take Columns out it seems to default to 3.